# regex to extract string between delimiters

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

i am trying break a string using the delimiter '_' (underscore) and extract specific values from it using regex. however as there are underscore characters inside each of the sub-string, i am having difficulty.

can you let me know how to go about this -->
string: `GOOGLE_CPC_(CAMPAIGN_NAME)_(AD_GROUP)_SEARCH`

i need to extract `CAMPAIGN_NAME` and `AD_GROUP` separately from the list.

i'll need this for google appsscript

Answer (score 0):

its not clear why you need to split it by underscore. If you just want to capture the values in the brackets you can just use a regex for that

```py
import re
mystring = "GOOGLE_CPC_(CAMPAIGN_NAME)_(AD_GROUP)_SEARCH"
matches = re.findall(r"\((.+?)\)", mystring)
print(matches)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['CAMPAIGN_NAME', 'AD_GROUP']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex does what you need.

```
[(](.*?)[)]
```

It matches the brackets, then groups all the characters within the brackets. You use the ? to filter non-greedy, so you get 2 groups, which are the group you need.

Comment: with this is there a possibility to just extract say only the second or the third match?

Comment: Yes. Like the other answers here, you can use findall and get a list of all the results. You can use result[1] to get the second result, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a solution in Google Apps Script, this snippet does the job for you:

```js
const str = 'GOOGLE_CPC_(CAMPAIGN_NAME)_(AD_GROUP)_SEARCH';
const result = str.match(/(?<=\()([^\(\)]+)(?=\))/g);
console.log(result);
```

It basically matches all values inside brackets and puts them inside the `result` array. Hence your campaign name is at `result[0]` and you your ad group at `result[1]`.

Let me know if this helps.